# What is a pythonic way to select data from one of two locations?

Tags: python, styles, readability

I am making a backwards incompatible change to an api endpoint in a different app that I call from a client app (where this code lives). I need to for a time support it handling both the previous case (where the data lived at the "ledger" level") and the new case (where the data lived at the "profile" ledger).

The code below works to grab it from either place but I have a nagging feeling there must be a more pythonic way to do this. Any ideas?

```
class Profile(object):

    @property
        def account_owner(self):
            owner_data_from_ledger = self.account.ledger.data.get('owner', None)
            owner_data_from_profile = self.data.get('owner', None)

            owner_data = owner_data_from_ledger if owner_data_from_ledger else owner_data_from_profile

            if owner_data:
                return Human(owner_data)
            return None
```

Comment: What are you looking to improve in your code? What makes you want it to be changed?

Comment: @MooingRawr I don't think there's anything "wrong" with it, I just would like it to be more beautiful if that's possible :)

Comment: I believe your code is beautiful as it is. It's readable which is the most important thing second to working, Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
owner_data = owner_data_from_ledger if owner_data_from_ledger else owner_data_from_profile
```

you can write this which is equivalent:

```
owner_data = owner_data_from_ledger or owner_data_from_profile
```

Alternatively shorten the whole thing:

```
owner_data_ = self.account.ledger.data.get('owner',
                  self.data.get('owner', None))
```

You can also leave out the `None` at the end above since that's the default value of that argument.

Comment: The thing with `or` is that if `owner_data_from_ledger` is 0 it will throw to the default. Now that's not an issue if 0 isn't expected. All I'm saying is, while `or` is a great trick, it needs to be used carefully, since `[], (), {}, '', None, 0` will all trigger it.

Comment: @MooingRawr yes, but that's exactly what the current code does too.

Comment: Fair enough, just thought maybe should mention it just incase in the future one of those might trigger issues.

Comment: @mooingRawr thanks for pointing that out, but i'm not expecting any falsey values here that I wouldn't want to ignore.